# OnValueChanged for fields in a Scriptable Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I use some kinds of OnValueChanged() or OnValueChanged Attribute on a variable/property in a class extented ScriptableObject in C# Unity to invoke another method whenever the value of that variable/property in its asset file is changed in inspector? Or is there anyway to serve that purpose?

Comment: You can implement the `OnValidate` function to detect when a value is changed in the inspector. However, the only way to now **which** value has been changed is to have a private "backup field" and compare the value with your serialized field.

Comment: Is this value you want to watch is of a custom type? If yes, you can add an event handler to it.

Comment: yes, it's a custom type and it's a variable in a class extended ScriptableObject. I created an asset file of that class, and I want a method to be invoked anytime I change the value of that variable(in the asset file) through inspector. And that method should be in the that class

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Custom Editors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) to archive this. Here is a minimal example that can monitor changes of both fields and properties

```cs
public class CustomType : ScriptableObject {
    public int myField;

    private int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set {
            if (value != myProperty) {
                // do stuff here
                myProperty = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnMyFieldChanged(int from, int to) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    [CustomEditor(typeof(CustomType))]
    class CustomTypeEditor : Editor {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
            CustomType customType = (CustomType)target;

            int field = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Field", customType.myField);
            if (field != customType.myField) {
                customType.OnMyFieldChanged(customType.myField, field);
                customType.myField = field;
            }

            customType.MyProperty = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Property", customType.MyProperty);
        }
    }

#endif
```

This will only work if you open this opject in the inspector. If you want this object as part of another object you have to use [Property Drawers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) instead. These are very similar to custom editors.
This is a very basic example to show that it is possible to solve your problem with a custom editor, but you probably want to look more into the topic if you plan on using them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple propertydrawer solution can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Bahamutho/8079a84915dc1adb65761a0a0327f70d), if your class is not inheriting from monobehavior for OnValidate() or want to avoid making a custom editor for each class. Also below a simple implementation and example:

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Reflection;

public class OnChangedCallAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public string methodName;
    public OnChangedCallAttribute(string methodNameNoArguments)
    {
        methodName = methodNameNoArguments;
    }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(OnChangedCallAttribute))]
public class OnChangedCallAttributePropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property);
        if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            OnChangedCallAttribute at = attribute as OnChangedCallAttribute;
            MethodInfo method = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == at.methodName).First();

            if (method != null && method.GetParameters().Count() == 0)// Only instantiate methods with 0 parameters
                method.Invoke(property.serializedObject.targetObject, null);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OnChangedCallTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool UpdateProp = true;

    [SerializeField]
    [OnChangedCall("ImChanged")]
    private int myPropVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myPropVar; }
        set { myPropVar = value; ImChanged();  }
    }


    public void ImChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log("I have changed to" + myPropVar);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(UpdateProp)
            MyProperty++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea - thank you - however this code as-written doesn't seem to work for compound Inspector fields such as System.Serializable structs. The little 'expand' arrow appears, and the callback is invoked each time it is clicked (and it toggles as expected), but the lower-level structure's fields don't appear in the Inspector any more. Any thoughts as to how to extend this to make it work in this case?

Comment: @davidA try to replace `EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property);` with `EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);` in order to include children.

Answer (score 1):

The free [NaughtyAttributes](https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes) Asset has the attribute [OnValueChanged](https://dbrizov.github.io/na-docs/attributes/meta_attributes/on_value_changed.html?highlight=onvaluechanged) which you can use to trigger when a value changes via Inspector. Here is an example with a drop down list visible in the Inspector:

```
[Dropdown("LevelNames")]
[OnValueChanged("OnLevelChanged")]
public string currentLevelName;

private List<string> LevelNames {
    get {
        return new List<string>() { "Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3" };
    }
}

private void OnLevelChanged() {
    Debug.LogFormat("OnLevelChanged: {0}", currentLevelName);
}
```