# In Unity, How to Trigger the Set Method When Changing Boolean Value in the Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have the following class attached to a game object:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private bool aBool;

    public bool ABool 
    {
        get 
        {
            return aBool;
        }
        set 
        {
            Debug.Log("we are setting the bool!");
            
            // triggered when changing from false to true
            if (aBool == false && value == true) 
            {
                // do stuff
            }

            // triggered when changing from true to false
            if (aBool == true && value == false)
            {
                // do stuff
            }

            aBool = value;
        } 
    }

    // Other fantastic methods and etc here.
}
```

When I play my game and check the aBool checkbox on the game object in the inspector, the set method is not being triggered. My debug log statement is not triggering, so it looks like it is not entering the set method.

How do I trigger the set method when I set the boolean in the inspector window, when playing the game? Have I done something wrong when creating the property?

Comment: I think it is useless to use set, get in C# to find if an attribute is changed in the inspector of unity because they are different. I suggest using EditorGUI to detect changing in your field

Comment: The Inspector is not aware of any properties .. it only shows you the exposed serialized **fields** ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Inspector itself is not aware of any [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in your class. It will always only expose the serialized [**fields**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). See also [Unity Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html).

A *Field* and a *Property* are very different things. You do **not** simply add setter and getter to a *Field*, but rather convert your *Field* into a *Property*.

What you see and edit in the Inspector is **not** the *Property* `ABool` but rather the *Field* `aBool` which itself is in no way aware of that a property `ABool` with setter and getter exists at all.

The confusion might be caused by the Inspector automatically formats th names of all exposed fields for a "human readable" display

- Always starting with a capital letter
- inserting spaces when switching from a lower case to a capital letter
  (basically treats every capital letter or number and all lower case letters behind it as one word)
- ignoring leading `_`
- some special cases like ignoring leading `m_`

So basically no matter if you call a field one of

```
public bool aBool;
public bool ABool;
public bool _aBool;
public bool _ABool;
public bool m_aBool;
public bool m_ABool;
```

the Inspector will for all them display `A Bool`.

---

One way that was mentioned is using [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) which s automatically called when a value of this component was changed via the Inspector and do e.g.

```
private void OnValidate()
{
    // Only call properties during PlayMode since they might depend on runtime stuff
    if(!Application.isPlaying) return;

    ABool = aBool;
}
```

In your case though the issue will of course be that `value != aBool` will never be `true` since `aBool` already was set to the value.

In order to avoid this you would need to introduce yet another control flag

```
[SerializeField] bool aBool;

private bool _oldABool;

public bool ABool
{
   get => aBool;
   set
   {
       aBool = value;
       
       if(aBool != _oldABool)
       {
           if(aBool)
           {
               // do stuff
           } 
           else
           {
               // do stuff
           }
       }

       _oldABool = aBool;
   }
}

private void OnValidate()
{
    // Only call properties during PlayMode since they might depend on runtime stuff
    if(!Application.isPlaying) return;

    ABool = aBool;
}
```

---

Another way would be to implement your own field attribute like e.g. mentioned in [OnValueChanged for fields in a Scriptable Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223969/onvaluechanged-for-fields-in-a-scriptable-object)

Answer (score 1):

Posting for anyone else in the same situation.

In unity, when you have a bool exposed in the inspector, which also has a property overriding the set method, it does not call the set method when the bool is set in the inspector. Instead, it is modifying the bool directly.

If you want to be able to change a bool in the inspector and detect when it is changed in a script, you will need to poll for changes in the update function.

This makes my particular use case a bit more verbose, but oh well.

Comment: You can also use OnValidate but it won't automatically tell you which variable has changed.

Comment: This is kind of obvious since what you see in the Inspector is **not** the property `ABool` but rather the serialized field `aBool` which in no way is itself aware that `ABool` exists at all ...

Comment: @derHugo yes I misunderstood how it works. Never used properties in c# before. I was assuming that there was always an internal set method that could be overridden by creating a property.

Answer (score 0):

I think anyone did not notice that OP is setting abool variable and has getter and setter on Abool variable .Obviously setter and getter will get triggered when read write happens on Abool not abool. But OP is setting abool instead of Abool. Also properties (variables with get/set methods) can not be exposed in inspector to be set by inspector by yourself. They can only be altered through code.

Comment: I think I pretty much noticed and explained this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999470/7111561) though ;)